# Storing sql credentials inside an azure subscription

Tags: azure

I am wanting to clone a copy of our production database onto our QA server as part of our continuous integration program.

There doesn't appear to be a method in Azure to clone a database just yet so I am exporting and importing the database via blob storage.

I am having trouble with the following commands (ommiting the unimportant stuff):

```
$SqlCtx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName $ServerName -UseSubscription
$exportRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlCtx -StorageContainer $Container -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -BlobName $BlobName
```

Which returns the following error.

> Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport : Cannot bind parameter 'SqlConnectionContext'. Cannot convert the 
>       "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.Server.ServerDataServiceCertAuth" value of type 
>       "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.Server.ServerDataServiceCertAuth" to type 
>       "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.Server.ServerDataServiceSqlAuth".

I am quite sure that this is because I don't have any sql credentials in my subscription so the sql connection doesn't know how to connect. Does anybody know how I can make this work?

Comment: I am running into this exact same issue. It seems like you can only do export requests if I use a user name and password, but heck, I don't want those in plain text in some script.

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, you need to provide Sql credentials. One way is to ask the user for credentials using `Get-Credential`, like in the example for [Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546720.aspx):

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$SqlCtx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName $ServerName -Credentials $credential
$StorageCtx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageName -StorageAccountKey $StorageKey
$Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Context $StorageCtx
$exportRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlCtx -StorageContainer $Container -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -BlobName $BlobName
```

Azure Sql server credentials are managed separately from Azure credentials, (just like VM logins), that's why it's not enough to provide Azure subscription credentials.